# Azure DevOps - teamMemberID vs AssignedToUserSK

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using API to retrieve some data from AzureDevOps. I am using this end point to get data about a given team's members:

```
https://dev.azure.com/organization/_apis/projects/some id/teams/some other id/members?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

When I expand the identities I am getting this

```
{
Id: "19d0f452-3981-7777-9e9a-8e4f3baa8a0d",
Descriptor: {
IdentityType: "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity",
Identifier: "fad75a54-a323-4cd0-3456-6a8d57035aa8\someone"
},
ProviderDisplayName: someone,
CustomDisplayName: null,
DisplayName: someone,
IsActive: true,
UniqueUserId: 0,
IsContainer: false,
Members: [ ],
MemberOf: [ ],
Properties: {
SchemaClassName: "User",
Description: "",
Domain: "fad75a54-a323-4623-8e51-6a8d57035aa8",
Account: someone,
DN: "",
Mail: someone,
SpecialType: "Generic",
PUID: "aad:",
ComplianceValidated: "2021-04-08T00:00:00Z",
http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier: "96dd81ce-48e3-4675-bf4b-59ae1604408b",
DirectoryAlias: someone
}
}
```

I am also using Analytics View to get the history of iterations. I have been trying to link the identities with analytics view using id field from identities with AssignedToUserSK from Analytics View but it looks to me they are not the same. In case of two members out of a dozen I can't link them. The AssignedToUserSK are different than the member's ids. What am I missing? Can somebody explain it to me in simplified English? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my test, the teamMemberID and AssignedToUserSK are the same.

The response of [Teams - Get Team Members With Extended Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20team%20members%20with%20extended%20properties?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) api is as below:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "identity": {
        "id": "3b5f0c34-4aec-4bf4-8708-1d36f0dbc468",
        "displayName": "Christie Church",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber1@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/3b5f0c34-4aec-4bf4-8708-1d36f0dbc468",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=3b5f0c34-4aec-4bf4-8708-1d36f0dbc468"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity": {
        "id": "8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
        "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity": {
        "id": "19d9411e-9a34-45bb-b985-d24d9d87c0c9",
        "displayName": "Johnnie McLeod",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber2@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/19d9411e-9a34-45bb-b985-d24d9d87c0c9",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=19d9411e-9a34-45bb-b985-d24d9d87c0c9"
      }
    }
  ],
  "count": 3
}
```

The id in this response is the same as AssignedToUserSK in PowerBI.

Comment: but do you have any idea what might be the reason that they are not the same in my case? How come is this possible?

Comment: It seems the response you got in your post is different from mine, did you run the correct api?

Comment: Have you checked your api? Are you able to get response as mine?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: It is not going at all. I have checked my API and it is correct. I may know the answer next week from somebody who is said to be a matter expert.

Answer (score 0):

After studying documentation:
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORG/YOUR_PROJECT/_odata/v3.0-preview/$metadata

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/data-model-analytics-service?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-available-in-analytics?view=azure-devops

I come to a conclusion that there are two different GUIDs describing the user: UserSK and UserID. For data retrieved via Analytics View it is UserSK. Via API it is
UserID. In some cases the two GUIDs can be the same. Why? No idea.

To get both one needs an additional call to analytics via odata. Below find an example:
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORG/YOUR_PROJECT/_odata/v3.0-preview/Users?$select=UserId,UserSK,UserEmail